# Space collasping Tokenizer/Filter in Solr

Tags: solr

I have a multivalued field in SOLR schema. I am wondering if there is an existing tokenizer/filter which can just removes a space. For example, given "solr,apache solr,inverted index", I would like to have them as "solr,apachesolr,invertedindex".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory) as the first entry in your analyzer chain during index time for that field. So define a new fieldType in your schema.xml as follows:

```
<fieldtype name="text_no_ws" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" 
                pattern=" " replacement=""/>
    ...
```

and then use that as the type for your field, like:

```
<field name="keywords" type="text_no_ws" multiValued="true" ... />
```